# React + TypeScript: Passing React Component as Props, rendering with props [Error: TS2339]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-component

I am using React + TypeScript.
I have a scenario where I have to pass a `React.SFC` component to another component. Which I am doing like this:

**Container.tsx**

```
import ChildComp from './ChildComp';
<ParentComponent CustomComp={ ChildComp } someArray={ [1, 2] } />
```

Now the issue is, I want to iterate this `ChildComp` component with `someArray` value, inside `ParentComponent`.

This child Component has it's own prop `someValue`, and I have added types to it, like what this child component can accept, and I am passing this prop while iterating it inside Parent.

**ParentComponent.tsx**

```
const content = someArray.map((value, index) => (
  <CustomComp someValue={ value } key={ index } />
));
{ content }
```

But I am getting error, that `TS2339: Property 'someValue' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.`

Although, if I directly use above iteration in `Container.tsx` where I am importing it, it works fine. But not working if I am passing it to another component.
Am I missing something here?

**Note:** Since the same iteration is working on `Container.tsx`, I am passing the iterated content to `ParentComponent` and rendering it like a variable:

```
{ CustomComp }
```

This works, but I want to know why the other solution did not work.

**More details**

**ChildComp.tsx**

```
type Props = {
   someValue: number,
};

const ChildComp: React.SFC<Props> = ({ someValue }) => {
   return (
      // Content
      { someValue }
   )
}
```

Type of CustomComp, in `ParentComponent`:

```
type Props = {
   CustomComp?: React.ReactNode | null
};
```

Before it was `React.ComponentType`, but I was getting error, so I changed it ReactNode, since I am directly passing content now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CustomComp` prop isn't typed properly. It accepts a component (`CustomComp={ ChildComp }`), not an element (`CustomComp={ <ChildComp /> }`). In this case it would be not `React.ReactNode` but `React.ComponentType`.

It's also not random component but specific component that accepts `someValue` prop. `ParentComponent` props likely should be typed as:

```
type ParentCompProps = {
   CustomComp: React.ComponentType<ChildCompProps>,
   someArray: number[]
};
```

Comment: I was passing it as { ChildComp }, because I want to render it inside `ParentComponent`. And since it expects props, which are inside `ParentComponent`, that is why did not passed as `{ <ChildComp /> }`. But I think if I define  `ChildCompProps`, it will solve the problem. Let me test that.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. That is what I was missing, prop validation for CustomComp. I was just defining `CustomComp: React.ComponentType`,  needed to add `<ChildCompProps>`.